# .htaccess with codeigniter redirecting

Tags: php, codeigniter, .htaccess, redirect

I am using codeigniter trying to achieve this

```
test.html redirect to 

index.php/test/test
```

well 1st test  is folder name

& 2nd  test  is controller

Comment: dont use `.htaccess` for things that framework provides you in default [(routing)](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For test.html you can do it like this you .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^test.html$ index.php/test/test [L]
```

OR in `routes.php` you can also define a route

```
$route['test.html'] = 'index.php/test/test';
```

Comment: taking your suggestion i remove .htaccess and doing from routing  

$route['test.html'] = 'index.php/test/test'; 
but it redirecting to 404..
by the way i am using CI controller...

Comment: @JaffarRaza do not remove the complete `.htaccess` file just remove these lines and in then add in routes.php